# Website redirect and DNS entry for website hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, dns-hosting, web-applications, web-services

We have web application that is hosted on on premise Windows Server 2008 R2. 
We were previously accessing it via **http://xx.xx.xx.xx/WebApp**

Just few days ago, we bought a SSL certificate issued to (XXX.XXX.ca) and installed it on the web server and now we are accessing that site via **https://xx.xx.xx.xx/WebApp**.

I would like to access website from the browser via XXX.XXX.ca rather than IP address. 
The server is in Domain environment. Where do I need to make DNS entries so anyone can reach to the application without IP address?

Comment: Do a `ipconfig /all` and see what the DNS server locally are. Then add the A record on the DNS server.

Comment: @shinjijai So I did that and we are using local DNS Server. I added a A record with internal IP address. It still doesnnt work. I can access the site via IP but not with name. Sorry I dont know anything about DNS

Comment: For your site in IIS, did you bind it to *:443 or a specific host name? I suggest you bind it to whatever the xxx.xxx.ca on 443 and make your cert you purchased is selected as well.

Comment: Yes I bound Https to port 443 with IP address *. When I select Http it gives me option to type host but when I choose https , the host field is disabled.

Comment: What do you get when you do `nslookup xxx.xxx.ca`? Also your DNS, did you added that DNS record in the XXX.ca zone? or somewhere else?